# Program has returned control to the operating system in Assembly 8086

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-16, emu8086

When I run my program the assembler says:

> PROGRAM HAS RETURNED CONTROL TO THE OPERATING SYSTEM

when it reaches the *RET* instruction. The code looks like:

```
twoMash PROC
    push bp
    mov bp, sp
    sub sp, 2

    NOT ax
    ADD ax,1

    mov sp,bp
    ret
twoMash ENDP
```

`main` is defined this way:

```
main:
    mov ax,100b
    push ax
    call twoMash
```

Comment: Which assembler are you using? Also, the question doesn't make sense. When you *run* the program, the *assembler* does something? The assembler isn't executing when you're running the problem. Do you see this message when attempting to assemble your code, or when attempting to run the binary? Are you sure that this is actually an error?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What is the code **after** `call twoMash`? You didn't post it but it probably ends the program (like `mov ax,4c00h` , `int 21h`).

Comment: There is nothing after call twoMash @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez

Comment: Maybe that's why your program ends, because there is no more code.

Comment: Add something after `call twoMash`, for example, display a string : `sst db 'Hello World$'`, `mov ah,9`, `lea dx,sst` , `int 21h`.

Comment: Did you create a COM program or an EXE? A COM program would have had `org 100h` in it. I wonder if you created a COM program and the twoMash function was executed first, reached the _RET_ and then that returned back to the OS without ever reaching `main` . It is hard to tell unless we saw your complete code.

Answer (score 3):

The first instruction is `push bp`, so value on top of stack is now value from `bp`.

Then you do some more things, including manipulation of `sp` (pointer to top of stack), but just before `ret` it points back to the old `bp` value.

`ret` will pop value from stack, and set `ip` (instruction pointer) to that value. Under normal circumstances it is expected to have on top of stack the address of next instruction to execute (put there usually by `call` instructions, which does the counter-action of `ret`, push address of next instruction after `call` on stack, and then sets `ip` to the argument value from `call` instruction).

But in your code the `ip` is set to old `bp` value, which very likely points somewhere into stack memory (or "worse"), so the CPU will next try to execute data bytes as code, and the behaviour is unexpected (return to OS would be actually quite nice end result, such mistakes usually end in crash of application, or even loss of data).

To fix, add `pop bp` ahead of `ret` (after restoring `sp` value by `mov sp,bp`).

Whenever you manipulate stack, either explicitly by `push/pop` or `add/sub sp`, or implicitly by `call/ret`, make sure you end with correct `sp` value in every code path before using stack further. Ie. usually every `push` needs it's pairing `pop` and every `call` should return by `ret`, unless you are experienced enough to break such rules and adjust stack to correct state by different means.

---

BTW, it is questionable, whether there actually *is* return address at the stack at your entry point (it's not clear from your question, if you have some other code `call`-ing this, or it is entry point of your program).

If this is like DOS executable, and it was entry point, then you should end your program with [`int 21h, 4Ch`](http://spike.scu.edu.au/~barry/interrupts.html#ah4c) OS service call.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an error, the program has finished successfully, but if this message bothers you, you can use the `HLT` at the end of the code.  Then the program will stop successfully and show the following text:
`the emulator is halted`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).